# how to simulate barcode scanner for my java application?

Tags: java, barcode

I created a Java application and want to use barcode scanner in my Java application.
but don't have a device Barcode Scanner
How can I simulate a Barcode Scanner for testing my Java Application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on how you want the scanner to connect to the system later on.

There are scanners that just use keyboard emulation. In that case you don't need to do anything (just make sure the right input box is active when expecting barcode input).

Other scanners connect to the system through a serial port emulation (for example, there's an USB to serial driver for Symbol/Motorola and Datalogic gun scanners). In that case, you open the serial port in Java and get scanner input as serial data. To simulate this, you'd have to connect your PC to another PC using a cross-over RS232 cable and could then use Hyperterminal/Putty/[whatever there is on linux or other OSs] to send data to your PC over the serial cable.

Comment: I've used Datalogic Scanners in a Java WebApp, i strongly recommend Keyboard emulation, and I hope that you'll receive a physical device before deploying the application to the Client :)

Comment: We're using most popular brands of scanners all the time in desktop apps (.NET, however) and I strongly advise *against* using keyboard emulation, as you have *no control* where the barcode goes. If you use COM connected scanners, you can decide (based on the barcode content) what you're getting and what to do with it.

Comment: I totally agree that testing with a real device is a *must*!

Comment: To acquire the barcode I used a separate window with an invisible, autofocused tiny textbox to receive the data... no way that the input goes somewhere else. But i agree that in a non-dedicated page, or in a desktop application, it could be harder to intercept it "in the right place".

Comment: One should also keep in mind that there are different barcode formats. Instead of just coding numbers within a barcode, other information (like "It's a storage bin code" or "It's an item" or "It's a control code for my program") can also be encoded. The application can then take action depending on the type of information. You lose this "feature" when using keyboard emulation. Whether keyboard emulation is a good solution highly depends on the complexity of the use case.

Comment: This is interesting... we did use PDF417, and encoded metadata at the begin of the message. Using serial port you can send metadata and content separately ?

Comment: Some scanners allow you to configure some sort of "data formatting" where you can say: "After scanning the barcode, take the first 4 characters, then send a separator, then send the rest". But usually, you just intercept the barcode before it is displayed in the application. It could also contain non-displayable characters (from the serial port, you get a byte array). With a keyboard emulation, you can not do that properly.

Comment: Aah, ok... (i used TAB as separator) Thanks for the infos

Comment: Which is actually some clever solution if you need to fill in several fields from the same barcode :-D

Answer (score 7):

If you are running your application from the console,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String barcode = scan.nextLine();
```

Otherwise just pass your barcode to `main` method args.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is actually a good answer. A barcode scanner is, from the POV of the java program, just a keyboard (standar input).

Comment: I actually downvoted your answer because it gave no explanation at all. Since then have been trying to take back my downvote, but I keep getting a message that my answer is locked in until the post is edited.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and found the [barcode-simulator](https://github.com/mroach/barcode-simulator) project on GitHub.  It covers a portion of the concerns raised in the comments, at least for the initial testing.

Still, there is nothing like the real deal.  Expect that the mix of real users and real scanners are going to find unexpected holes in your application.

Provide really clear input to your clients:

- When the users cursor is in the correct field have it change color and
  show a message like "Waiting for Scan",
- Clearly and quickly show if a scan is valid or invalid,
- Make it trivial to rescan.

If your users are clear about what the path of success looks like then it should be good.